# complex valued Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, lipschitz-functions

It is well known that a real-valued function $f: \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called Lipschitz continuous if there exists a positive real constant $K$ such that, for all real $x_1$ and $x_2$,
$$\Vert f(x_1)-f(x_2) \Vert \leq K\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert$$

A differentiable function $f: \mathbb{R}^{N\times 1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to have an L-Lipschitz continuous gradient if there exists a positive real constant $L$ such that, for all real $x_1$ and $x_2$, 
$$\Vert \nabla f(x_1)-\nabla f(x_2) \Vert \leq L\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert$$.

My question now is:

**How to express a differentiable function $f: \mathbb{C}^{N\times 1}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called Lipschitz continuous or L-Lipschitz continuous gradient?**
$$\Vert f(x_1)-f(x_2) \Vert \leq K\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert ?$$
$$\Vert \mathcal{D}_{x^*} f(x_1)-\mathcal{D}_{x^*} f(x_2) \Vert \leq L\Vert x_1-x_2\Vert?$$.

**Whether the function $$f(x)=\frac{x^H A x}{x^H B x}$$ satisfies Lipschitz continuous or L-Lipschitz continuous gradient?**

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you describe it in detail?  Please.

Comment: I mean, if $f\colon \mathbb C^n\to \mathbb R$, then the Lipschitz condition $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le L\|x-y\|$$ reads $$ |f(x)-f(x)|\le L\sqrt{ \sum_{j=1}^N |x_j-y_j|^2}.$$

Comment: Yes, $\vert f(x)-f(y) \vert \leq L\Vert x-y\Vert_2$. I tried a search on Google for these formulas. Unfortunately, I cannot find an explicit description of complex-valued Lipschitz continuous in a paper or a book.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, why you think Lipschitz continuity is any different for complex domains or how a function from the complex to the reals can be differentiable.

Comment: As inner product spaces over the reals, $\Bbb C^n = \Bbb R^{2n}$. The only difference is $\Bbb C^n$ comes with extra operations built-in. But those operations do not change the metric or anything about the definitition of Lipschitz. The only change to the L-Lipschitz condition is that it can also be applied to the complex version of the derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is still $\|\triangledown f(x_{1})-\triangledown f(x_{1})\|\leq L\|x_{1}-x_{2}\|$, and based on this conclusion, we can have $f(x)$ majorized as $f(x)\leq f(x_{t})+\Re\{\triangledown^{H}f(x_{t})(x-x_{t})\}+L/2\|x-x_{t}\|_{2}^{2}$, which is known as the Descent Lemma, where $x\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$ and $f$ is real-valued function.

Comment: could you provide a reference for this lemma? I've tried googling it but all I can't find are cs papers where the result is stated without any proof